# Stop on breakpoint in Eclipse facelet file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, facelets

I switched to use facelet in Eclipse.

Before, when I used JSP i could put breakpoint on the page.

How can I put now on a facelet page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow this [JSF Facelet tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSF%20Facelets%20Tools%20Tutorial.html) (which uses [facelets](https://web.archive.org/web/20070711181357/https://facelets.dev.java.net/), an extension to JavaServer Faces(JSF) that uses XHTML syntax to define a JSF page; it doesn't seem to allow breakpoints directly on the JSF page itself.

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/images/new-jsf-facelets-page.png))</sub>

The best bet remains in setting a breakpoint in the associated code:

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/images/loginbean.png))</sub>

, in order to debug that screen:

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.facelet.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/images/run-facelets.png))</sub>

---

The problem is: WTP facelet is an **[incubator project](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/incubator/)**, based on a [2008 proposal](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/incubator/proposals/JSF%20Facelets%20Tools%20Proposal.html), which apparently has not made it as an official project.
Its [project status](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JSF_Facelets_Tools_Project) is not exactly "current", if you catch my drift.

Comment: So this is my question - is there a way or there is no way to it?

Comment: @Mike: from what I can see, not directly in the JSF source itself, but hopefully in the Java code (in this example `LoginBean`). Try setting a breakpoint in the associated Java code and see if it works.